# What happens to memory after I call MPI_Init()?

Tags: memory, mpi

Suppose I have some code that looks like this:

```
#include "mpi.h"

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    int my_array[10];
    //fill the array with some data

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    // Some code here

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Will each MPI instance get its own copy of my_array? Only rank 0? None of them? Is it bad practice to have any code before `MPI_Init` at all?

Answer (score 8):

The short answer to "what happens to memory when I call `MPI_Init`" is: nothing.

`MPI_Init` initializes the MPI library in the calling process.  Nothing more, nothing less.  At the time of the `MPI_Init` call, all the MPI processes already exist, they just don't know about each other yet and can't communicate.

Each MPI process is a separately executing program.  The processes do not share memory, and communicate by passing messages.

Indeed, the processes calling `MPI_Init` can even be different programs entirely, as long as the messages they pass around match.  This is the MPMD model.

Comment: Could you me to documentation about dynamic process management and perhaps a few good pieces of example code?

Comment: The dynamic process management in MPI is quite limited.  The main restriction is that a communicator can't change once it's been created.  So once `MPI_Init` creates `MPI_COMM_WORLD` for the initial set of processes, it is impossible to add more to it.  What you can do is create a new group of processes using [MPI_Comm_spawn](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi22-report/node203.htm#Node203).  The new processes get their own `MPI_COMM_WORLD`, and an [intercommunicator](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi22-report/node143.htm#Node143) linking the two worlds.

Comment: This is true for memory, but you should be careful with things you do before `MPI_Init`. Some implementations may fork processes in `MPI_Init` or do whatever magic to setup their processes. E.g. the [MPICH Documentation](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/www/www3/MPI_Init.html) recommends not to modify external state before `MPI_Init`. When in doubt, do it after `MPI_Init`

Comment: @Zulan Thanks - I did not know of any implementations that did this, so I did some more research.  Apparently AMPI uses threads to implement MPI processes, but it converts global variables to private ones.  So in that case some very interesting things do in fact happen on MPI_Init :)

Comment: How could the processes calling `MPI_Init()` be different programs entirely? Wouldn't one still need to start the process using `mpirun`, and doesn't that only launch a single program?

Comment: `mpirun` can start different executables on different nodes.  One place where this is useful is in a heterogeneous cluster where nodes have different CPU architectures.  And lastly, `mpirun` is just a helper.  It will launch processes on remote nodes and let them know enough to communicate with one another, but strictly speaking it is not required to use MPI (you could implement your own launcher).

Answer (score 2):

When you run mpi code, you are running the same code in different process (they can not share memory), so each process will have his own array.

The arrays should be equal, unless your data depend of time (the process are not necessarily synchronized), process rank (I think the rank is only available after the init call) or any random number generators (some may generate random seeds as well).